# How is the number of profile view counted.

Tags: support, user-profiles

I would like to know how the number(count) of profile view is counted. 
1. Is it contain my session when I click my picture in the top bar of this site?
2. Is it contain my session when I click my picture in the left drawer?

Could you tell me about it?

[image: My profile view]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your profile views does not include you, *when you're logged in*. If you access your profile without being logged in, the system has no way of knowing whether it's you or a random other person, so it goes ahead and increments your profile view count.

As long as you are authenticated to StackExchange, whenever you view your own profile, the profile view count does not increment. But it increments for both anonymous/unregistered users, as well as registered users who view your profile.

Note that the counter only increments once for as long as the user has a stackexchange cookie in their browser, and it does not increment each time you refresh the page (assuming that you previously had a cookie). It also seems to wisen up to your IP address, so if you were to make a new Incognito/Private Browsing window, you can get at most 1 extra view on your profile with the anonymous account before it keeps it from increasing.

Over a long period of time, for an old account, those who frequently visit their own profile (bookmark, etc) will get a few "self-views" of their profile too -- for instance, if your authentication cookie expires and you have to re-login, and your ISP gives you a new IP, and you visit your profile, there's another view. But it's entirely dependent on whether you have a cookie and what the state of that cookie is (as well as apparently an IP check).

Comment: Thank you for tell me. It's very breif explaination